# Ways to set up routers with the same SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, ssid

I'm planning the network for the house I'm blueprinting. 
I intend to have three routers around the house. 
Conveniently, the company has a fiber optics modem with three ports.

Now,

Since the modem has three ports, I was planning on wiring ***modem to router A***, ***modem to router B*** and ***modem to router C***.

My intention was **NOT** to wire ***modem to A***, then ***from A to B***, then ***from B to C***, as some suggestions I been reading.

Can the former be done, leaving the same SSID to all the three routers?

Will the modem or router(s) themselves handle DHCP or other conflicts? 
If not, what should I set?

For network/printer/scanner compatibility reasons, they must all be on the same subnet.

The routers will each be connected to desktops and phones, so they should each provide wireless AND cabled connection interchangeably (nothing atypical; unless they still sell pure Wi-Fi or pure cabled routers).

At least, that was my plan.

I already have one router, and it is a cheap one. Not sure what features it supports, so, for the sake of simplicity, compatibility, and consistency, I'd be thankful if they all received similar settings.

---

**P. S.:**

As the question was quite longe, I left behind some "guidelines".

I also added things to the body above.

**Sorry if I don't answer everyone. Short on time. But rest assured I'm reading everything.
Thank you all, by the way**

1 - My intention was for simple and cheap. I have a WR840N router already. It chokes constantly, but it does the job... I expect only a marginally better equipment next house. Sorry to disappoint those expecting a state-of-the-art pet project.

1.1 - Many of you suggest (by my understanding) tha I use "repeaters" instead of wired routers. That seems (again, by my understanding) not different from the cascade topology, and all the problem it brings. Specially if the father Wireless device is not an expensive one...
Is this approach *faster* or *more reliable* or *more "inter-independent"* than cable ?

2 - Security, privacy, and above normal reliability are **not** important;

3 - I dislike cascaded equipment because all I need is for the first to fail for the others to fail subsequently. And since item #1...;

3.1 - What favours the *"star"* topology is the very central physical positioning of the Modem (ONU) on the house;

3.2 - It's up to you, the ones who understand, to confirm, but my intuition says *star* is "less layers", "less routings", "less NATs" (had to look up what it is, after *JW0914*'s comment), "less variation of configurations"...

4 - The house roaming is optional, specially if it will complicate the setup. A single SSID and password helps reducing the quantity of saved passwords, etc. That would be the priority.

---

To *davidgo*: I don't understand if the current Modem installed here has routing, but it does have DHCP on it's settings. If it IS a router device, the question is whether this "father" router will handle the theoretical 765 clients, or if this modem will give 3 IPs to each "son" and let the son routers handle 255 each. I ask you all, who understand about this subject, to think about this "balance" (how much will every device handle), after we decide the topology. My intuition say that we shouldn't overload the Modem.

To *Reinstate Monica*: long ago I configured a LAN to a small office. Can't remember how many devices there was, or how I configured it. All I remember is: Windows did not see other computers that were on different subnets. The same thing for Printer and scanner sharing: They were shared, but the computers from another subnet couldn't find.

[image: My plan - star configuration, with modem connected to each router]
[image: Not my plan - serial/chain, with A connected to B and thence to C]

Comment: How to configure a router as a wireless repeater for the primary WiFi router is different with each router - the OEM should have a how to/wiki article on their site or within the router's manual. General FYI: it's better to go Modem to Router A, A to B, and A to C for data privacy, else the ISP maintains remote access to your LAN. Provided you request the ISP to provide a WAN only connection from one of the modem's ethernet ports and to disable any LAN bridging, you won't be double NAT'd with router A and downstream devices

Comment: Buy a [mesh Wi-Fi router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network) system and don’t think about kluging this stuff together like that.

Comment: Your plan is almost certainly going to be completely impossible using the stock firmware on consumer based routers. They are just not designed to work they way you are expecting. You possibly could do something if you can replace the firmware and bridge the LAN/WLAN interfaces together, but this would a very complicated setup, that would likely not be reliable at all. Anyway, tell us the specific router hardware you have, as in specific models for the fiber 'modem' and all three wireless 'routers'.

Comment: (1) I assume “roaming” is a requirement — as you move around the house, any devices you carry should switch to the closest router (i.e., the one that provides the strongest signal). If so, you should probably say so. (2) Are you 100% sure that you need the entire house to be a single LAN segment? (You know that routers normally *connect **separate*** LAN segments, right?)  (3) If you could get a single LAN segment house-wide with multiple SSIDs, would that be a problem? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: What make and model is the modem, and why have you deployed 3 routers?  (I posit the modem is actually a router. If thats the case, simply reconfigurebthe routers as AP's, and assign the ssame SSID and password (but different. non-overlapping channels) for *almost* seemless roaming.

Comment: @Zoredache: It's nowhere near impossible - most home routers _already_ bridge the LAN and WLAN interfaces together (it's just one subnet, not two), only the WAN interface isn't bridged but nothing forces one to actually use the WAN interface at all. What it _is_ is likely not very reliable and possibly headache-inducing, but it's been done many times, including even on this site.

Comment: @giacomo1968 Most modern routers support configuring the router as a WiFi access point, granted you gain more flexibility with routers compatible with opensource firmware like OpenWrt, as routers generally use one of two main WPA packages [`wpa-supplicant` || `wpad`], with the specific package of either determining whether the full or partial version is installed. A mesh system would work, and could also be configured via OpenWrt, but it would be more efficient to first determine if the OP's routers support being configured as WiFi access points before spending money on a mesh system.

Answer (score 2):

From any modem you should have one connection, to a router. The router routes on layer 3, IP protocol, i.e. 192.168.1.1. There should be one router for your system, because there is one IP subnet in your lan. Networking switches route layer 2, MAC address, so you can have much more flexibility in configurations, and you save a layer (routers use layer 2, MAC,  and translate it to layer 3, IP protocol.). So switches are faster and more robust than routers for lan use.

You really don't require WiFi routers, because the WiFi in them generally sucks! And the security in home networking equipment is abysmal. So, you want to divide up into one  wired connection off the modem to the wired router (no WiFi at this level.).

Use dedicated, managed WAPs and managed networking switches. Forget the router on the modem. They are absolute trouble makers lacking features. Run one output on the router (decent routers allow to assign a range of IPs to each port rather than 1 IP.) to a switch. Connect other terminal switches (the ones at the desktops) to the main switch off the router.

Connect the WAPs  (wireless access points) to the terminal switches. If this is a new house, you can supply AC power for each access point. But due to the locations generally chosen for WAPs, PoE is preferred (1 cable vs 2: power and Ethernet can both go over PoE.).

Mobile devices (moving WiFi targets) will roam from one WAP to another if the signal on one becomes degraded (due to distance). So, you can give each WAP it's own unique set of SSIDS (quality WAPs generally have at least 2 radios, low band and 5GHz, each with up to ~6 configurable SSIDs.

I use Watchguard routers and WAPs, and managed switches by Netgear, D-link, Cisco, Ubiquity, or T-link. You want managed, because each port can be configured. You want much different configurations for a WAP, and say, a printer or phone. VoIP requires precedence for its packets, and managed switches allow that option.

The way you had planned the system might seem like it will just work, but chances are it will not work very well, and the performance might be very poor and difficult to diagnose why. And, you'd just be disabling the DHCP servers everywhere but the modem. You can't have >1 DCHP server on a single subnet. OR, yes you can, but it's redundant and chaotic.

I can't possibly fit everything into one answer. If, after reading what I have written, you believe your original plan will work, you should go with it, and just bookmark this question for future reference.

I hope this helps! I learned the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

> 4 - The house roaming is optional, specially if it will complicate the setup. A single SSID and password helps reducing the quantity of saved passwords, etc. That would be the priority.

Roaming *will* happen whenever you have a single SSID shared across several Wi-Fi access points. You cannot tell most client devices that the 3 access points sharing an SSID are actually different networks that must not be roamed to. So if you want to share an SSID house-wide, you must include roaming as part of the design as well.

> Can the former be done, leaving the same SSID to all the three routers?

Yes, it's entirely possible, but **only if** the "modem/ONT" in your diagram also performs IP routing (and NAT), and the "routers" do not.

As mentioned above, as long as you try to share the same SSID across several access points, your client devices *will* try to automatically roam between them, and if those access points provide access to different IP networks weird things will happen.

This means your diagram would look more like this:

[image]

The router *may* be the same device as the ONT (many ISPs provide combined routers + ONTs), or they can be completely separate, but there still needs to be only one of them.

Ideally, the "bridge" devices would be dedicated Ethernet switches (for wired ports) and dedicated Wi-Fi access points (for Wi-Fi).

Most random wireless routers can be used as the "bridges" for providing Wi-Fi, as they almost always have Wi-Fi and Ethernet LAN ports bridged together – as long as they do not *function* as routers in this setup. The usual steps for achieving that (though already repeated in dozens of threads on this site) are:

1. Disable the "DHCP server" and "UPnP" services in all routers to be used as bridges.
2. Configure the "LAN" IP addresses of each bridge to be within the same subnet, but not conflicting with each other nor with the main router. For example, if the router is 192.168.1.1/24, then the bridges could be .2, .3, and .4 in the same network.
3. In all routers to be used as bridges, use one of the LAN ports for the upstream connection. Do not use their WAN port for anything, *unless* the device has a specific option for "bridge mode" which adds the WAN port to the main LAN/WLAN bridge.

> 3.2 - It's up to you, the ones who understand, to confirm, but my intuition says star is "less layers", "less routings", "less NATs" (had to look up what it is, after JW0914's comment), "less variation of configurations"...

Somewhat true, but in this situation (a shared SSID necessitates no more than one router, all access points being in "bridge" mode) it actually wouldn't make much of a difference – several L2 bridges can be chained together without any impact to L3 (routing) topology.

Though of course, direct star connection is still better in many cases (more reliable, easier to troubleshoot) but there may be exceptions.

> The routers will each be connected to desktops and phones, so they should each provide wireless AND cabled connection interchangeably (nothing atypical; unless they still sell pure Wi-Fi or pure cabled routers).

They do – in larger enterprise networks, those are completely separate functions. The router has no Wi-Fi capability at all (and is likely rack-mounted); all wired devices (including the Wi-Fi APs) are connected through dedicated Ethernet switches; and all wireless devices through dedicated Wi-Fi access points that have no IP routing or NAT capabilities and with a single Ethernet port for the uplink.

You can find lots of cheap 5/8/16-port Ethernet switches on sale, whose only job is just to provide more Ethernet ports for desktops and phones. Dedicated Wi-Fi access points are fewer, but they do exist (among other things, some "extenders" often have such a mode, and 'prosumer'-grade APs like UniFi are not uncommon).